# Convert to Dictionary and Fill missing items

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a query as follows:

```
IDictionary<ClassificationLevel, Int32> stats = context.Exams
  .GroupBy(x => x.Classification)
  .Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
  // ...
```

The dictionary ClassificationLevel is has follows:

```
public enum ClassificationLevel { L1 = 1, L2 = 2, L3 = 3, L4 = 4 }
```

My problems are:

1. How to convert the result of the query to IDictionary
2. The items with Count 0 will not appear in the dictionary.
   How to make sure those items appear with value 0.

**UPDATED**

To get the best performance I think the following should be made:

```
IDictionary<ClassificationLevel, Int32> stats = context.Exams
  .GroupBy(x => x.Classification)
  .ToDictionary(x => new { Key = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
```

This would close the EF query ...

Then I would find which keys are missing, e.g. which ClassificationLevel items are missing, and add those keys with value 0.

How should I do this?

Comment: [`Enumerable.ToDictionary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549277%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for #1.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I am using EF so Exam is a POCO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a single linq expression.

```
var stats = context.Exams
    .GroupBy(x => x.Classification)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, g => g.Count()) // execute the query
    .Union(Enum.GetValues(typeof(ClassificationLevel))
        .OfType<ClassificationLevel>()
        .ToDictionary(x => x, x => 0)) // default empty count
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key) // group both
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Sum(y => y.Value)); // and sum
```

Comment: The Union is not being accepted ... I get the error: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<AnonymousType#1,System.Linq.IGrouping<Classification,Exam>>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Union<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you use `(x => new { Key = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })` or `(x => x.Key, g => g.Count())` ? `ToDictionary` can accept 2 parameters, first is key, second is value, use two parameters should work

Comment: Nice catch ... That was the problem. Thank you. I am working to mark the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use [`Enumerable.ToDictionary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549277%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and then [`Enum.GetValues()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to fill in the missing values:

```
        IDictionary<ClassificationLevel, Int32> dict = context.Exams
            .GroupBy(x => x.Classification)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
        foreach (ClassificationLevel level in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ClassificationLevel)))
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(level))
                dict[level] = 0;
```

Or, if Entity Framework balks at the `ToDictionary()`, I believe you can do the following:

```
        IDictionary<ClassificationLevel, Int32> dict = context.Exams
            .GroupBy(x => x.Classification)
            .Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count);
        foreach (ClassificationLevel level in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ClassificationLevel)))
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(level))
                dict[level] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ["Left Outer Join"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) in LINQ, after that you can use `GroupBy` + `ToDictionary`:

```
var query = from classification in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ClassificationLevel)).Cast<ClassificationLevel>()
            join exam in context.Exams on classification equals exam.Classification into gj
            from subExam in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { classification, exam = subExam };
IDictionary<ClassificationLevel, Int32> stats = query
    .GroupBy(x => x.classification)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: But am I not loading all items into memory that way? I would like to avoid that, if possible ... So the count should be done on the database.

Comment: @MDMoura: i have overlooked the entity framework tag. So i'm afraid that this won't help you. (i'm not familiar with L2Entities)

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it like this

```
var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof (EnumType)).Cast<EnumType>().ToArray();
Enumerable.Range((int) enumValues.Min(), (int) enumValues.Max()).ToDictionary(
                        x => x.Key,
                        x => context.Exams.Count(e => e.Classification == x)
                        );
```

Comment: He wants an `IDictionary`, not an `IEnumerable` of anonymous type. What happens when a new classification gets added?

Comment: adjusted my answer though it's kindof straightforward

Comment: Aren't you making one count for each item in the dictionary? Imagine the dictionary has 20 items that means 20 queries to the database ... Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In that case you would have to intersect the 2 collections, but that would have been premature optimization as I don't know the exact circumstances

Comment: I updated my question ... Maybe the solution would be to get the Dictionary from the database and then fill the missing values.

Answer (score 0):

This code allows you to loop around your enum.
    foreach (ClassificationLevel level in (ClassificationLevel[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(ClassificationLevel)))
    {
    }

You could then put something like the following in the middle of the loop:

```
if(!stats.KeyExists(level))
{
   stats.Add(level, 0);
}
```